# How to setup Grails in the sublime editor

Tags: grails, sublimetext

I installed Grails and Sublime editor on my system. From the command line Grails is working. But when I run any Groovy file from Sublime editor it throws an error that Groovy is not recognized as an internal or external command. What else should I do in order to setup Grails in the editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to execute files from the editor, the process is to create a file from the command line generally after the grails commands then work on the file from the editor for example a controller and evaluate its operation from the browser or Testing.

If you need to run a groovy file individually you can do it from [groovyConsole](http://groovy-lang.org/groovyconsole.html)

Comment: do you mean, from editor a `.groovy` file is not supposed to be excuted?